# How to make nav at bottom stick to top

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav, sticky

I am not very experienced in jQuery so I have been struggling with what I have been trying to accomplish recently.

I want a nav that is at the bottom of the window to stick when it reaches the top.

[What it should look like before and after scrolling.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1ov443kdio8jyer/AADguX-xF7IprFIc-2OOzRgba?dl=0)

I have tried methods like:

```
var stickyNavTop = $('nav').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {  
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyNavTop) {
        $('nav').addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
        $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
    }  
});
```

[Here is the entire HTML and CSS](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6u7j9ojyctxz47t/AADT5l9G-XXymLsrVi-DAD3Wa?dl=0)

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: every once in a while you should update your `stickyNavTop` offset value. You know... users often resize their browser etc...

Comment: Also **don't** put code in DropBox. Create a [mcve] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is check the offset top of your element you want to check is at the top of the screen. If it is we then simply add a new class which has fixed position and top 0;

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6jczdjdj/

```
$(function() {
  var distance = $('.navbar').offset().top,
    $window = $(window);

  $window.scroll(function() {
  $('.navbar').toggleClass('fixedtop', $window.scrollTop() >= distance)
  });
});
```